# Add Javascript Keydown event from C# to a textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

I'm building a set of text boxes from asp.net repeater and trying to add a key down event from C# code to those text boxes to prevent user from entering a specific character (`comma(,)`). I can't use the text box id itself in Javascript because its built dynamically with diff id's. Now I have no idea how to pass the `e` object to the textbox's keydown event from C#.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

**Code Snippet :**

```
 TextBox txtTextField = e.Item.FindControl("txtAns_1") as TextBox;
 txtTextField.Attributes.Add("keydown", "PreventChars(" + txtTextField +")");
```

**Javascript**

```
   function PreventChars(e) {

            var k = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

            if (k.match(/,/g))
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

> use **ClientID**
>
> ClientID returns The control ID for HTML markup that is generated by
>   ASP.NET.

**Change Code Snippet to:**

```
TextBox txtTextField = e.Item.FindControl("txtAns_1") as TextBox;
txtTextField.Attributes.Add("keydown", "PreventChars(" + txtTextField.ClientID +")");
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't exactly understand how passing the ClientID as an object works, but it does work. You need to dig a bit on the front-end to get the event argument but you can find it under `e.keydown.arguments[0].key`.